# node.js convert emojis into unicode or something else?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unicode, emoji

I am trying to mess around with the `facebook-chat-api` NPM package. I am trying to check whenever the `message.body` contains a fire emoji () it will execute some logic. But how would I go about getting the unicode (? Not sure what I actually need) of this emoji in Node.js. I've tried `utf8` NPM package but it does not seem like it is working

This is the response I see in the terminal:

```
{     
      type: 'message',
      senderID: 'senderID',
      body: '',
      threadID: 'threadID',
      messageID: 'messageID',
      attachments: [],
      timestamp: '1518288429669',
      isGroup: false 
}
```

Answer (score 4):

For emoji to unicode convertion u can use [emoji-unicode](https://www.npmjs.com/package/emoji-unicode) package:

```
const emojiUnicode = require("emoji-unicode");

console.log(emojiUnicode(""));
// => 1f525
```

And for emoji name to unicode, You can use [emoji-name-map](https://www.npmjs.com/package/emoji-name-map) package:

```
const toEmoji = require("emoji-name-map");

console.log(emojiUnicode(toEmoji.get("fire")));
// => 1f525
```